# load array saved in text file into javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I would like to load a text file with an array like the one below so it is accessible within javascript, how can I do that via an ajax call to access the text file? This is the text file `artists.txt`:

```
["Fally ipupa","Radio & Weasel","P-Square feat. Don Jazzy","Mose Fanfan","Fally ipupa","Mercy Masika","Madilu System","Koffi Olomidé","DaVido","Luciano","Kanda Bongo Man","Franco","Franco","DJ Afrobeat","Oliver Mtukudzi","Sauti Sol","Alikiba","Aryon","Gramps Morgan","Buju Banton","Wailing Souls","Bob Marley & The Wailers","Don Carlos and Gold","Burning Spear","Peter Tosh","George Nooks","Richie Spice","Culture","Sanchez","Terry Linen","Archie Wonder","Jah Cure","Busy Signal","Romain Virgo","Junior Reid","Shaggy","Glen Washington","Ginjah","Lucky Dube","Bushman","Chronixx","Turbulence","Protoje","UB40","Franco","Rich Mavoko","Rose Muhando","Kanda Bongo Man","Diamond"," Davido","Tekno","Daddy Owen","Pépé Kallé","Busy Signal","Franco Et Le T.P. O.K. Jazz","Alice Kamande","Koffi Olomidé","Culture","Alikiba","Papa Wemba","Korede Bello","Madilu System","Reuben Kigame","Gloria Muliro"]
```

Comment: Can you include `js` tried at Question? Is file local or remote resource?

Comment: To all down voters, it does not help the question by just down voting it, please suggest a way to improve the question

Comment: @LouieAlmeda By following one of the primary recommendations for asking a good question, which is to include evidence of an attempt. The question is currently "I want some code to do this thing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call it via ajax directly using GET request.

```
/**************************************************************************************************
Ajax
*/
    // Set all of these parameters.
    // type
    // url
    // callback
    // data


    Pub.ajax = function (config_ajax) {
        var xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();

        // post_json
        if (config_ajax.type === 'post_json') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        }

        // post
        if (config_ajax.type === 'post') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        }

        // get
        if (config_ajax.type === 'get') {
            xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
        }

        // post for form_data
        if (config_ajax.type === 'multi') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);

        }
        xhr.onload = completed;
        xhr.send(config_ajax.data);

        function completed () {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                throw new Error("xhr.status is " + this.status);
            }
        }
        xhr.app_url = config_ajax.url;
        Priv.createStatusBar(xhr);

        return xhr;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work through Ajax call,

1. Rename your file as artists.json
2. Set MIME type in your web server,  as application/json for .Json extension. This would be already set in most of the webservers.
3. Then do an Ajax call,  if you use library like jquery then it is pretty straight as follows

   url=my site.com/artists.json;

   ```
   $.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: success
   });
   ```

This should automatically allow you to fetch and read the JSON file in your success method.